# allow to run javascript code right in visual studio

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, compiler-construction, interpreter

Sometimes i need to write a couple of lines of code on javascript just to check how it works or try some algorithm. I use VS as primary tool, and it looks annoying for me that I can't run javascript code right in VS in REPL manner, like Ruby for example.

So my question: is it possible to run javascript right from VS, maybe it's possible to to that with some plugins or add compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Its really simple to do so. IE provides debugger tools. There are many ways to do this.

Here is a list of things I would possibly do

1. Use Chrome by simply pressing F12 and clicking on console for REPL (The debugged and REPL have fantastic features)
2. Use IE by simple pressing F12 too. It support breakpoints and the feel is very similar to Visual studio.
3. Use visual studio immediate window.

Hope this helps. Regards.

Comment: I know that it possible to do that inside browser. But I need to do that in IDE. Immediate window is something closer to what i need, but it still do not allow me to write and run code in usual manner.